# Calculate Date Difference for unique Premise IDs for email data

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframes as follows:

```
RefNo TopicNo BillA/c PremisesNo Date Age TopicType 
  1    111     1234     54698    11/12/18  APSR
  2    222     5698     123654   12/12/18  KLPO
```

I need to find all occurences of PremisesNo and find out respective date difference.

```
RefNo TopicNo BillA/c PremisesNo Date Age TopicType Diff
  1    111     1234     54698    11/12/18  APSR      1
  2    222     5698     54698    12/12/18  KLPO      0
  3    333     5798     54698    12/12/18  KLPO      NA
```

I have tried following code:

```
df2 =[]
def occurence(df1):
for ind, row in df2.iterrows(): 
    if ind in df['Premises Number'].unique():
        df2.append(df1['Premises Number'])
 return df2 

occurence(df1)
```

But it's not giving required solution. Need some advice.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP2Pk.png)

Comment: Date difference with respect to what? The preceding values?

Comment: yes @nixon! difference for current row date and preceding row date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `PremisesNo` and take the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) of the `DateAge.diff` column:

```
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('PremisesNo').['Date Age'].diff(-1).abs().dt.days
```

Using your sample dataframe:

```
         TopicNo  BillA/c PremisesNo Date Age   TopicType
RefNo                                                   
1          111     1234       54698 2018-12-11      APSR
2          222     5698       54698 2018-12-12      KLPO
3          333     5798       54698 2018-12-12      KLPO
```

First turn the `Date Age` column to datetime, and do as above:

```
df['Date Age'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Age'], format = '%d/%m/%y')
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('PremisesNo')['Date Age'].diff(-1).abs().dt.days

         TopicNo  BillA/c  PremisesNo  Date Age    TopicType  Diff
RefNo                                                         
1          111     1234       54698   2018-12-11      APSR   1.0
2          222     5698       54698   2018-12-12      KLPO   0.0
3          333     5798       54698   2018-12-12      KLPO   NaN
```

Comment: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

Comment: Why don't you share a larger sample of `df` so I can test it. Make sure there is more than one repetition of `PremisesNo`

Comment: df['Diff'] = df[['PremisesNo','Date Age']].groupby('PremisesNo')['Date Age'].diff()
df.loc[df.PremisesNo != df.PremisesNo.shift(),'Diff] = None

Comment: @nixon: I added sample dataset image to original post.

Comment: Please @ParagS, don't paste images data, paste the data itself. And if you want to group by `PremisesNo`, make sure there are repetitions of it to see the time difference

Comment: Thank you very much @yatu. I need this difference in number or integer format. How would I go about it.

Comment: Updated the solution. Please consider accepting if it solves it for you @ParagS

Comment: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'> exception and unconverted data remains: 18 0:00 error  @yatu.

Comment: @yatu : can you guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @nixon answer, try this

convert 'Date Age' to pandas DateTime

```
df['Date Age'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Age'])
df['Diff'] = df[['PremisesNo','Date Age']].groupby('PremisesNo')['Date Age'].diff()
```

When PremiseNo changes then make the difference None

```
df.loc[df.PremisesNo != df.PremisesNo.shift(),'Diff'] = None
```

Comment: Thank you @Vaibhav, it helped me.